# How to Test an optional member of an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

What is the best technique to test an optional object member.  Right now we are prefacing the expect statements with an if:

```
 if(object.member) expect(object).to.have.a.property('member').that.is.a('string');
```

but there must be a method that is more inline stylistically.  E.g.

```
 expect(object).to.have.an.optional.property('member').that.is.a('string');
```

or (adding would as an empty chain, for readability):

```
 expect(object).to.have.an.optional.property('member').that.would.be.a('string');
```

or (moving the optional to provide an alternative version of expect):

```
 optionally.expect(object).to.have.a.property('member').that.is.a('string');
```

---

update - I started to write this code (new to chai) to see if I could accomplish what I was targeting, so I added a small plugin:

```
module.exports = function(chai, utils) {
    var Assertion = chai.Assertion
        , i = utils.inspect
        , flag = utils.flag;

    var OPTIONAL_FLAG = 'chai-optional/option'
    Assertion.addProperty('optional', function() {
        flag(this, OPTIONAL_FLAG, true)
        return this;
    })

    Assertion.overwriteMethod('property', function (_super) {
        return function assertProperty (propertyName) {
            if (flag(this, OPTIONAL_FLAG)) {
                flag(this, OPTIONAL_FLAG, false) ;

                var obj = this._obj;
                var isPropertyPresent = (obj[propertyName]) ? true : false ;

                if(isPropertyPresent) {
                    return _super.apply(this, arguments);
                }

            } else {
                _super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    });

    Assertion.addProperty('would', function () {
        return this;
    });
};
```

WIth usage:

```
it('could be null or have a value', function(done){
    var objWithout = {}
    var objWith = {}
    objWith.someProperty = 'blah'

    expect(objWith).to.have.optional.property('someProperty').that.would.be.a('string');
    expect(objWithout).to.have.optional.property('someProperty').that.would.be.a('string');

    return done();
})
```

The current problem even when the property isn't present, the control of the function ends - but the evaluation chain continues.  I need to end the evaluation with out a failing assertion - is this possible?

---

update either solution (simplistic solution):

```
var either = function(firstCondition){
    var returnObject = {}

    try{
        firstCondition()
        returnObject.or = function(secondCondition){ return }
    } catch(e) {
        returnObject.or = function(secondCondition){ return secondCondition() }
    }
    return returnObject ;
}

module.exports = either
```

I think the implementation is a little clunky - but fat arrow functions will hap thin out some of the syntax. So here is waiting on that!

Comment: Moving `optionally` to the beginning would have different semantics which don't make sense.

Comment: I agree - i was using it as an option of potentially triggering a  second form of expect perhaps optionallyExpect(object) may be better.  But the problem is semantically better solved by having optional to the right of the expect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The current problem even when the property isn't present, the control of the function ends - but the evaluation chain continues. I need to end the evaluation with out a failing assertion - is this possible?

After having read about chai's [plugin](http://chaijs.com/guide/plugins/) [guide](http://chaijs.com/guide/helpers/) I would have used a similar approach with a flag. However, I have reached the same conclusion - you cannot simply stop a chain.

A possibility I though of would be not only to implement new properties and a new flag, but to overwrite the `assert` method itself - to not throw when the `OPTIONAL_FLAG` flag on the current `Assertion` object is set. However, the chance to destroy everything or to miss an edge case is too hight.

After all, I don't think it's a good idea. Citing from [this "confusing syntax" issue](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/261):

> I think the misunderstanding comes from your expectation that Chai
>   follows most/all English grammar rules. Unfortunately, English grammar
>   has way too many rules (and exceptions to those rules) for it to be a
>   reasonable undertaking to implement.
>
> The challenge with designing Chai's chain-able assertions is finding
>   the balance between being expressive and concise. Even if full grammar
>   wasn't a daunting task to implement and document, it would make the
>   API less concise, which is not good for a testing environment.
>
> > RULE: Any "flag" which modifies the behavior of an assertion (negation
> >     not  or inclusion  include/contain , etc...), once set to  true 
> >     should remain  true  until the end of the chain.

This means it is impossible to implement something like an `.or` operator as well.

What is possible though would be to implement something like

```
either(function(){
    expect(object).not.to.have.a.property('member');
}).or(function(){
    expect(object).to.have.a.property('member').that.is.a('string');
});
```

Maybe one can build a more appealing syntax on that.

Comment: added my implementation of either / or.

Comment: Yes, that's what I though of :-) Another idea was an `Either` instance that acts as a proxy which remembers property accesses and method calls (getters for all known names), and can replay them on access of `or`. So you could literally write `expect(object).either.not.to.have.a.property('member').or.to.have.a.property('member').that.is.a('string');`